# Is it safe to use a Map/Reference Object in the reactor context?

Tags: project-reactor

What if I put a Map/Reference Object in reactor context?

```java
Mono.just(1)
        .flatMap(item -> {
            return Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> {
                Map<String, String> temp = ctx.get(CONTEXT_KEY);
                // put something into MAP. <1>
                temp.put(MAP_KEY, "value");
                return Mono.just(item);
            });
        })
        .flatMap(item -> {
            return Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> {
                Map<String, String> temp = ctx.get(CONTEXT_KEY);
                // effected by context which modified in operators above. <2>
                // print `value`
                System.out.println(temp.get(MAP_KEY));
                return Mono.just(item);
            });
        })
        // put contextWrite at the down of the chain, ensure operators above could see the MAP.
        .contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put(CONTEXT_KEY, new HashMap<String, String>()))
        .subscribe();
```

As we all known, `context` will affect operators above it, and the order is `from z to a`. The example above put a `HashMap` in `context`, and modified it in step 1, which affect step 2. Now the order seems like `from a to z`, and I can use it like a `ThreadLocal`.

So I want to known is this operation legal? Does any performance issues occur if the MAP is very big? Or does it cause a thread-safe problem?